# Opening new tabs in Chrome using Watir causes problems using open tabs

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, tabs, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Short version: new tabs in Chrome prevent old tabs from being used, fixing that means that opened tabs with PDFs in them get reused before a human can examine the PDFs.

Long version:
Originally it worked like this:

1. open new Chrome window to main page of the app (tab #1)
   2.[do process A and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #2) opens with PDF A in it.
2. Go back to tab #1 [do process B and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #3) opens with PDF B in it.
3. Go back to tab #1 [do process C and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #4) opens and Word document C document gets downloaded.
4. Go back to tab #1 [do process D and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #5) opens and Word document D document gets downloaded.

All tabs stay open and PDFs can be viewed.  Not perfect, but workable.

But then things changed. I pulled frequently used stuff out, put them in methods in another file so all of the various tests could use them, which seemed like a good idea. But that seems to have caused problems with losing focus on the original window. (I may be wrong) now I'm stuck with:

1. open new Chrome window to main page of the app (tab #1)
2. [do process A and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #2) opens with PDF A in it.
3. Stay in tab #2 [do process B and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #3) opens with PDF B in it. PDF A is now lost
4. Stay in tab #3 [do process C and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #4) opens and Word document C document gets downloaded. PDF B is now lost
5. Stay in tab #4 [do process D and then] click the button and a new tab (tab #5) opens and Word document D document gets downloaded.

This was caused by using "b.windows.last.use"
So I tried using "b.windows.first.use"
But that fails, because focus isn't going back to tab #1, and watir can't find the object in the modal that it needs to click. 
(in `assert_ok': Element is not clickable at point (737.5, -373) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError))

So far as I can tell, I would be fine if I could do any one of the following

1. get PDFs to download. I cannot. [This page](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/watir-general/gItPeAaWZWY) seemed promising, but the code didn't work and I couldn't fix it.
2. get watir to go back to the first page, "for realsies", and find the buttons it needs
3. perhaps open a new tab for every section of the test (I'm going to look into this one, but I'm not overly hopeful)

Any ideas?
I updated Watir and Ruby both within the last two months. I'm using Chrome on OSX. Moving to Windows or IE are not viable options.

Here is a section of the code. No, I'm not a programmer first and foremost.

Thanks.

```
currenturl = "stackoverflow.placeholder.com/works"    

# print Inventory Report .PDF (document 1)
b.goto currenturl
b.div(:id, 'page').a(:text, 'Inventory Report').click 
sleep 1
b.div(:id, 'printInventoryReportModal').a(:text, 'A4').click
b.link(:id => "submitBTNprint-inventory-report").fire_event "onclick"

# print General List .PDF (document 2)
b.goto [main page URL]
b.div(:id, 'page').a(:text, 'General List').click 
sleep 1
b.div(:id, 'printGeneralInventoryListModal').a(:text, 'A4').click
b.link(:id => "submitBTNprint-general-list").fire_event "onclick"

# print General List .DOC (document 3)
b.goto [main page URL]    
b.div(:id, 'page').a(:text, 'General List').click 
sleep 1
b.div(:id, 'printGeneralInventoryListModal').a(:text, '.DOC').click
b.div(:id, 'printGeneralInventoryListModal').a(:text, 'A4').click
b.link(:id => "submitBTNprint-general-list").fire_event "onclick"
```

Comment: Two things,  it might help to just reduce this down to one of the parts of code that calls your common helper methods, and then also include the code for those methods as well.   Secondly I'll point out that for items such as the print Inventory Report one, I never see it set or even use 'currenturl' yet it's passing that variable (well, the value IN the variable that is) to the page_status and section_results methods

Comment: Without providing the code from the helper methods, it's very hard to have a full picture, and likely you will get zero answers.  Also for the other tabs that open, are there things like, oh useful titles that might be able to be used to allow the .window methods to properly locate which tab you want?  That is less haphazard than using .last and .first to locate the tab you want to work with

Comment: Chuck,
First:  thanks for the input.

The problem remains even without the common helper methods, so I removed them from the above code. I added a placeholder for "currenturl" just for completeness.

As for naming tabs, I tried using `b.window(:title => "tab_name").use do` but that didn't help either. So far as I can tell, it fails because the browser doesn't actually change focus back to the first/last/specified tab, and the modal that appears on that page isn't accessible without focus.

Comment: OK but I don't see anything in the code above that tries to set the browser window to point to a different tab..  Nor have you indicated where the code goes astray or at what point you start getting errors etc.  It's hard to understand 'what is wrong' for you.  What do you mean when you say 'PDF A is now lost' what happened to it? is it not still in tab #2?   When you mention 'modal' are you referring to some kind of psuedo modal implemented with a div, or a true Javascript modal dialog (like an JS Alert)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems mostly that the browser.window function is not working the way you expect, or you are not using it properly.   Since your question currently contains very little in terms of examples of how you are trying to change windows (tabs) it's very difficult to tell what you might be doing wrong.

To start with I would use IRB to do some exploring and troubleshooting

Get into IRB, then use

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Now manually navigate the browser window that opens and get it into the state where you have multiple tabs open

Now try something like this in IRB to see if you can get it to spit out window titles

```
b.windows.each {|window| puts window.title}
```

If the titles are different, then you should be able to use that to set which window you want to use.  If they are not different you will need to look at other attributes to see if there is an easy way to identify which window you want.  (or maybe just use :index)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

**sleep (2)**

```
@browser.driver.switch_to.window(@browser.driver.window_handles[put_your_index])
@browser.window(:title,"Please put your title here").use do
end
@browser.button.when_present.click
```

1. when you want to want to switch back to your actual window, use the
   same code as above and change the window index accordingly.

For an example, if parent window index is `0` and then child window index would be `1`